# Free program to remove hidden files from USB sticks

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, usb

I am looking for a *free* program that automatically removes all the useless hidden files from a selected USB drive.

The files I'm talking about are the ones like `.Trashes`, etc... (essentially all the ones that start with `.` (a period/full-stop).

Requirements:

- free
- runs on Windows 7 64 bit (and OSX 10.6.8 if possible)

Comment: for OS X, already inlcuded. The `Terminal.app` and remove the files with `bash` script. Or, use `AppleScript` or `Automator.app` workflow.

Comment: What makes you think that **every** file starting  with `.` is "useless". Some _may_ be, but the origin of this naming is with Unix, where files which were important to system stability were so named. They wouldn't show up on a normal directory listing so that well meaning newbies wouldn't "tidy" them and destabilize the system. You might want to rethink a blanket approach to such files.

Comment: @Mawg You're right, but my use case was for removing files from a USB drive, and *I'll* never have any system files on my USB, therefore this will work *for me*. Anything starting with a period, to me, on my USB, is useless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following Python script to remove every file and folder starting with `.`. Install Python, `cd` to the root of your USB key and type `python hidden_file_remover.py`:

```
# Save this script as hidden_file_remover.py in the root of your USB key:
import os
import shutil
import sys    

def main(folder_path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):
        for dirname in [d for d in dirnames if (d.startswith("."))]:
            dirfullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
            print dirfullpath
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(dirfullpath)
            except:
                pass

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):     
        for filename in [f for f in filenames if (f.startswith("."))]:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print filepath
            os.remove(filepath)                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        folder_path = str(sys.argv[1])
    except:
        folder_path = "default_folder_path"
    main(folder_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can be more helpful. Although it is a compression tool there is an inbuilt explorer (far better than the Windows 7 one) in 7zip which can be used as another way to view/remove hidden files.